# Rejecting hypothesis after performing a logistic regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, games

I was analyzing a dataset that consists of 20000 chess matches. My hypothesis was that when ratings of players increase, the probability for white to win also increases. I was thinking of performing a logistic regression for this, 0 value as 'black wins' and 1 value as 'white wins'.

However,  I am unsure if logistic regression is the correct model in this situation, as in logistic regression, 0 and 1 values are mostly used for possibilities. Is there a better model to analyze if there is a correlation between white winning and players' rating?

Comment: In your case, $1$ will mean that black (or white) wins, and $0$ will mean that black (or white) does not win, which means that white (or black) wins (assuming no ties). Whatever software you use should be able to handle the factor variable of “black” and “white”. Just pay attention to which gets coded as $1$ and which gets coded as $0$.

Comment: If my hypothesis is false, does that mean the model will have a linear line like '--' shape instead of  a shape like 'S'?

Comment: If it is the case that the probability of white winning does not depend on player rating, then you should get a horizontal line, since only the intercept would be nonzero (the intercept would be zero if and only if there is a 50/50 chance if white winning). Empirically, you would expect to have some nonzero value on your player rating coefficient, so some curvature in the plot. There are ways of doing formal hypothesis tests and confidence intervals for that parameter, which may be more among the lines of what you want to do. Likelihood ratio seems to be the preferred method.

Comment: Why not just make a 2d plot with the elos on the players on x,y axes and coloring each point according to wether black or white wins? This way you can have a visual idea if there are correlations and how strong.

Comment: @Thomas makes sense, but in that case, how can I produce a line that shows correlation? Or is there no need for such a line

Comment: Chess also has draws. How do you plan to tackle draws?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What would you think of the binary classes being "white wins" and "white does not win"?

Comment: @Dave: Maybe ... While the asker expects white win percentage to increase with rating, I would expect it to fall, because that %draw increases with rating. Just compare a WC match with the typical club tournament! Maybe takin black wins and draws together hide such patterns?

Comment: (1) You don't want to ignore draws, because they provide information.  Consider an ordinal regression.  (2) It would be more informative to control for the opponent's rating.  A natural way to do that is to include the *ratings difference* as an explanatory variable.